# Is anyone familiar with this strange logo resmbling 'nfw'?

Tags: culture

I see bumper stickers, t-shirts, etc all over the place when passing by Christian colleges with this strange logo that I believe is somehow affiliated with Christianity but I'm unable to identify it.

It looks like there is an 'n' on the left, a 'w' on the right, and something I can't discern in between, possibly an 'f' or a cross or something. The typeface is kind of script or Cyrillic or something. Here is a bad recreation of it:

[image]

Am I confused? Is this logo unrelated to Christianity? Can anyone identify it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually NOTW, and stands for *Not Of This World*:

[image: Not Of This World logo.]

It's a reference to Jesus's words in several places, including [John 18:36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+18:36&version=ESV):

> Jesus answered, “My kingdom is not of this world. If my kingdom were of this world, my servants would have been fighting, that I might not be delivered over to the Jews. But my kingdom is not from the world.” [ESV]

The logo itself is that of an [apparel company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_of_this_World_(apparel)) that was founded in 2001.

Comment: Wow! I am impressed. Although I admit I'm surprised, I would have thought it was a clothing brand or some type of marketing material.

Comment: How old is the acrostic? Don

Comment: @sirdank Sure enough, you are right; it is an apparel company as well.  I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: @rhetorician The apparel company was founded in 2001, so that's probably the best date. There are other uses for the acronym, like [*News of the World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_of_the_World), that make it tough to nail down the Christian version of it.